# how to add component/content section in homepage

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm new to Joomla, but I can't figure out how to add a component to a page. But I am assigned the menu in Back-end and added the component link also. Hence its not showing in Front-end. I'm very confused what I want to do for the showing the component.

The same problem in content/article part also. The module was works perfect in all pages. I don't know why the contents part is not showing in all pages.
I am using Joomla 2.5 Template.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add following code in your template file where you would like to show the content.

```
 <jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Comment: Yeah Thanks for your help Rahul.. Its useful for me.

Now its works perfect. I really appreciate..